# When would you use the ModelFactory.getModels method?

Tags: rally

In the 2.0 API, the ModelFactory includes a getModels() method, but it is not clear how or when you would use it.  Does anyone know if this is capable of loading two types of Portfolio Items in the same function?  If so, are you restricted to retrieving a single item at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's exactly what it is for.  Here is an example loading two types:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels({
    types: [
        'portfolioitem/feature',
        'portfolioitem/initiative'
    ],
    success: function(models) {
        //use models here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! In the success: function, I assume that you have to use two separate model.load() methods to retrieve data from a specific feature and a specific initiative (e.g., models.load(featureOid, and a models.load(initiativeOid,...)

Comment: One more question: I looked at the docs and the syntax for referencing one of the models in your example is escaping me - How would you set a variable to get the reference (var x = models.?????)?  In reality, these are the same models, but the "/" in the types entry is a problem.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't occur to me to use the standard notation.  It does, of course, work.  My problem now is figuring out how to most efficiently join the results of the two get() methods to match story data to portfolio item data that can't be directly retrieved.